# Symbolic integration in Grapher.app?

Tags: menu-bar, bug, ui, grapher

Several months ago I was using Grapher, something strange happened. Instead of going to `Equation → Integrate`, I clicked the symbols menu (with the summation notation, cube root, etc.) and clicked the integral there instead. Now, whenever I do `Equation → Integrate` it does the silly integral computation instead of the symbolic integration which is so much better. The silly integral computation struggles to compute an integral of 2x to the left of the y-axis, although it may have its uses with integrals which cannot be solved symbolically. <s>It used to say about symbolic integration [here](http://guides.macrumors.com/grapher) but now that page isn't working so now it's turned into a bit of a conspiracy theory.</s>

Does anyone have access to the original symbolic integration? Has anyone else experienced this bug?

I have been meaning to ask this somewhere for a while, also, I have no evidence that the symbolic integration even existed so anything about that helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are some options about integration in Grapher Preferences.

You can also try deleting its preferences file `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.grapher/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.grapher.plist`

Comment: Thanks, but I think these preferences are already getable from ⌘, <kbd>Command+comma</kbd> or Grapher → Preferences in the menubar, I was asking specifically about whether symbolic integration from <code>Equation → Integrate</code> still works or whether I am imagining it ever existed